# Данил - родительный падеж.

Tags: грамматика, ономастика

Как будет в родительном падеже Данил: Данила или Данилы

Answer (score 2):

*"Данил"* - в родительном падеже будет (кого?) *Данила*.

Но надо учитывать, что в русском есть два употребительных варианта имени: *Даниил* (исторический и церковный) и *Данила* (обрусевший, некогда считавшийся просторечным). У них родительный падеж - *Даниила* и *Данилы*.

Вариант *Данил* тоже встречается, но много реже двух других, обычно выступает только как разговорный. Поэтому, если есть возможность, уточните прежде всего, имеет ли носитель этого имени именно такой вариант его написания.

Comment: У него в свидетельстве о рождении записано Данил, на Орловщине я встречаю этот вариант нередко!

Comment: Тогда все правильно. **(кто?) Данил, (кого?) Данила, (кому?) Данилу**... "Данилы" (в родительном) тут невозможно, поскольку соответствует другому варианту имени.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: Данила. А от имени Данила - Данилы.

Comment: В документах записано Данил

Comment: Если в документах Данил, тогда:  Данила.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно, оно же по-мужски звучит: Даниил, Даниила

Comment: Вопрос-то об имени **Данил**. Про **Даниила** только я вспомнил в ответе. И при чем тут корректность? Спрашивают про родительный падеж.

Comment: Имя Данил - неполное ( от Даниэль).

Comment: Если хотите что-то дополнить - правьте ответ.

Comment: Как же неполное, если в документах так указано!?

Comment: Неполное имя, попавшее в документ, полным от того не становится. Ну, лет через сто, если.

Comment: Пустая мысль, высказанная в комментарии, умной не становится. **Галина**, не обращайте внимания. У этого товарища стиль такой. Лишь бы чего сказать. Если написано в документах, значит это полное имя. Этим оно и отличается от кратного.

Comment: Неполное имя, появившееся по желанию родителей, остаётся их заботой, как в данном случае: не всякий поймёт, как пишется (на слух пропуск одной буквы чреват ошибкой большей, чем пропуск слога), и как склонять (Галина это ощутила на себе). Спите, товарищ, спокойно!